# reading large json file with panda

Tags: json, pandas

I am trying to load books reviews from this page
https://nijianmo.github.io/amazon/index.html I downloaded the file to extract it but when I try to read it with pandas I get memory error

```
pd.read_json('path/Books_5.json',lines=True)
```

I tried other files that are smaller and it worked
I am doing sentiment analysis I need 250k reviews with scores of 4,5 and 250k reviews with scores 1,2.

i tried to use this to check for the score and take the text into lists to make a data frame with  them later

```
with pd.read_json('path/Books_5.json',lines=True,chunksize= 1) as reader:
for chunk in reader:
    if chunk[chunk['overall'] > 3]:
        pos_revs.append(chunk['reviewText'])
    elif chunk[chunk['overall'] < 3]:
        neg_revs.append(chunk['reviewText'])
    if (len(pos_revs) == 250000) & (len(neg_revs) == 250000):
        break
```

but i got the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

looking at similar questions json files are not the same this how mine looks like[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading lines one at a time into DataFrames just to check their rating is incredibly inefficient, it's better to treat everything as dictionaries and make some Series at the end.

```
import json
import gzip
import pandas as pd

def parse(path):
    g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
    for l in g:
        yield json.loads(l)

file = parse('Books_5.json.gz')
pos_revs = []
neg_revs = []
while len(pos_revs) < 250000 or len(neg_revs) < 250000:
    line = next(file)
    rating = line['overall']        
    if len(pos_revs) < 250000 and rating > 3:
        review = line.get('reviewText')
        if review:
            pos_revs.append(review)
    if len(neg_revs) < 250000 and rating < 3:
        review = line.get('reviewText')
        if review:
            neg_revs.append(line.get('reviewText'))

pos_revs = pd.Series(pos_revs)
neg_revs = pd.Series(neg_revs)

print(pos_revs)
print(neg_revs)
```

Output:

```
0         The King, the Mice and the Cheese by Nancy Gur...
1                                        The kids loved it!
2         My students (3 & 4 year olds) loved this book!...
3                                                   LOVE IT
4                                                    Great!
                                ...
249995               Great read. Dis t want to put it down.
249996                                     Love this series
249997    So I am one of those people who absolutely lov...
249998    I learned a great deal from this book. The Fre...
249999    Having already read Tuchman's book on the outb...
Length: 250000, dtype: object

0         Looking for a Louis Untermeyer book  from the ...
1         Completly boring!!! Yes it's a childerns book ...
2         I don't like Hillerman novels.  It was chosen ...
3         I have read many of the Hillerman books and en...
4         I really love Hillerman's books.  He is one of...
                                ...
249995    When I first started reading SUSPECT, I though...
249996    I really despised this book.  Sure it portrays...
249997    This is a bleak novel. The mindless violence t...
249998    Like the title says, this is not as good as Ch...
249999    Great concept. Predictable, poorly written sto...
Length: 250000, dtype: object
```

---

Or a purely pandas version could look something like this, and possibly be faster:

```
reader = pd.read_json('Books_5.json.gz',lines=True, chunksize=100000)
pos_revs = pd.DataFrame()
neg_revs = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in reader:
    if pos := (len(pos_revs) < 250000):
        temp_pos = chunk[chunk['overall'].gt(3)][['summary']]
        pos_revs = pd.concat([pos_revs, temp_pos], ignore_index=True)
        # OPTIONAL:
        pos_revs.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
    if neg := (len(neg_revs) < 250000):
        temp_neg = chunk[chunk['overall'].lt(3)][['summary']]
        neg_revs = pd.concat([neg_revs, temp_neg], ignore_index=True)
        # OPTIONAL:
        neg_revs.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
    if not neg and not pos:
        break

print(pos_revs)
print(neg_revs)
```

Output:

```
                                                  summary
0               A story children will love and learn from
1                                              Five Stars
2                                           Not Nice Mice
3                        One of my favorite kids' stories
4                   One of our families favorite books!!!
...                                                   ...
294397  PRATCHETT ON TOP FORM WITH THIS BRILLIANT NEW ...
294398        Pratchett's aphorisms get better and better
294399  Thief of Time - John Deakins for ABSOLUTE MAGN...
294400                           An absolute masterpiece!
294401                     Beautiful, Engaging, A Classic

[294402 rows x 1 columns]

                                                  summary
0                                               Two Stars
1                                  Don't waste your money
2                                    Tony missed the mark
3                              Don't Start with This One!
4                                         Nothing special
...                                                   ...
253377                         Not the caliber of "Naked"
253378                 "Weak Stories" b/w "One Ace Essay"
253379      Fast service - product smells of mildew/mold.
253380  Nothing new, classical narration, good against...
253381  This is a magnificent book-hardcover version b...

[253382 rows x 1 columns]
```

I'm not sure which method is faster, but both take less than a minute to run on the 6GB file.